# Where hugetlb controller is auto enabled?

Tags: cgroups, huge-pages

One kvm virtual machine (8 vcpus+8G memory) of Ubuntu 22.04 with cgroup2 system,

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
hugetlb controller included;
```

But another kvm vm (4 vcpus+4G memory) of Ubuntu 22.04 with cgroup2 system,

```
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers
cpuset cpu io memory hugetlb pids rdma misc
cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control
no hugetlb controller included.
```

You have to manually

```
echo +hugetlb > cgroup.subtree_control
```

, which is not as expected.

In linux kernel source code / systemd source code, I did not find the relevant processing of automatically enabling hugetlb or automatically disabling hugetlb.
Would you be kind to tell me where the code to automatically enable hugetlb lies?